# Running Powershell script using inline admin credentials to start and stop windows services

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have access as an admin on a machine and I have to Start, Stop and Restart some of the window services using the Powershell script. We don't want to have UAC prompt while running the script because only one user would have access to that machine. Also due to some specific requirements, we have to have run that script file by adding the admin credentials inside it.

Along with other solutions I have tried so far, the one close to what I am looking for is as follows

```
$username = "Domain\user"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)

Set-Service -Name Spooler -Status Running -PassThru -Credential $psCred
```

But I am getting following error.

> Set-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'Credential'. At line:6 char:53
>   + ... t-Service -Name Spooler -Status Running -PassThru -Credential $psCred
>   +                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand

**Update 1** (Trying suggestion)

```
Invoke-Command -credential $psCred -command {Set-Service -Name Spooler -Status Running -PassThru} -computername myComputerName
```

> [myComputerName] Connecting to remote server myComputerName failed
>   with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the
>   destination specified in the request. Verify that the  service on the
>   destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and
>   documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
>   destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If  the destination is the
>   WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze
>   and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (myComputerName:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken

**Update 2**

I had to enabled PSRemoting on machine using command `Enable-PSRemoting -Force -SkipNetworkProfileCheck` so `Invoke-Command` can execute but after repeating the command `Invoke-Command -credential $psCred -command {Set-Service -Name Spooler -Status Running -PassThru} -computername localhost` I got following error

> [localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the
>   following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>   + CategoryInfo  : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken

*Running the same set of command in elevated powershell window is working fine.*

Can you please guide me in the right direction considering I am newbie in the Powershell world.

Comment: The `Set-Service` command does not have a credential parameter. You could use `Invoke-Command -credential $pscred -command {Set-Service -Name Spooler -Status Running -PassThru}`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. After searching the reason I found that "-credential without -computername can't exist".

Please check the update in my question

Comment: Try `-computername localhost`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I have tried few steps related to your suggestion and shared findings in the **Update 2** of my question. Please take a look

Comment: In that case, you can try by running powershell as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28989750/52598) question

Comment: can you try replacing -command with `-ScriptBlock` as mentioned in the below answer. -command doesn't seem be a correct parameter name

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-7) of Set-Service

Can you try like this?

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$hostname = "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"
Write-Host $hostname
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock{ Start-Service -Name Spooler}
```

Also if you don't want to prompt for the credentials then you can store the credentials in the Windows credentials manager and get it from their in your PowerShell script. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59514546/8074328) for using credential manager with PowerShell

Comment: Thanks Kundan, but when trying following script

`$Cred = Get-Credential
$S = Get-Service -Name Spooler
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Service -InputObject $S -Status Running
}`

It throws error:

[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: That means command is now properly running but user does not have access to perform the activity

Comment: can you use `$hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME` to get the current machine name instead of using localhost and try the same script? See the updated script above.

Comment: Running `sc stop Spooler` in command prompt as different user giving
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.

Comment: try this one. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName MachineName.domain -Credential domain\username -ScriptBlock{ Start-Service -Name Spooler}`  change it to Stop-Service if you want to stop it

Comment: try the modified script in answer